# How to share data between two threads of different Classes in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

I have searched a lot but I can't find an answer which is working for me. Here are some relevant code snippets.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private String[,] _maze;
    private String _state;
    private int _start;
    private Boolean _finished = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var agent = new Agent(_maze, new ArrayList {_start}, _finished);
        var agentThread = new Thread(agent.Run);

        agentThread.Start();

        while (!_finished)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        //some other code
     }
}
```

And the Agent:

```
public class Agent
{
    volatile String[,] _maze;
    ArrayList _path;
    volatile Boolean _finished;

    public Agent(String[,] maze, ArrayList path, Boolean finished)
    {
        _maze = maze;
        _path = path;
        _finished = finished;
    }
}
```

I need to share the following variables: _maze and _finished, so that all possible Threads (in this case the form and the agents) can access the same data. I have tried the attribute `ref` and `volatile` and I have also annoteted the Agent class with [Synchronization].

It could also be important to know, that the Agent starts also other Agents with the same requirements.

In my case it's not important to synchronize the data (I think).

**Update:**
We should implement an maze solver with this particular algorithm: On every step, where the agent has more than one field he could go, he should clone himself and go all possible paths from there.
If one agent have found the target, every agent should stop and the Form class has to do some calculations like highlight the path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you marked the Agent's members as volatile?  You want agents to know when other agents are finished?  I think that part is unclear from your description.  If you just need to know if a particular Agent is finished, then you can use a callback to run when the Agent is finished rather then monitor it constantly.

Comment: If several threads access the same data you will need some synchronisation in order to achieve a consistent view on the data amongst the threads. I would recommend to look into `AutoResetEvent` and the `lock` keyword

Comment: If you wrap those 3 things up in a class, you can pass the reference to that instance to the Agent and work on those properties from anywhere. But I'm not sure if it makes sense that they all control the same "finished" indicator, as one could finish while others still run. More logic and examples about your usage of this are required.

Comment: Important to note, the `volatile` keyword doesn't do anything on it's own, but only hints the compiler of the behavior around that variable. I second thumb's recommendations. (personally, working with multiple threads in almost every project, I never actually used the `volatile` keyword).

Comment: I will try it with a lock block, thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: If you need to share some data between different objects (regardless of their types) you should put them in a shared container or declare them as shared. The shared container can be a class object that you instantiate once and pass to all the worker objects during or after their constructions; otherwise you can mark the existing fields as static and any Agent instance will access the same fields' values.

Comment: I fail to see the problem.  Your form can already access the agent through the `agent` local variable.  Your existing solution, while it has its problems (namely blocking the UI thread), doesn't have any issue making this data accessible to both threads.

Comment: I also can't see the problem, but the I can see that at least one agent sets the _finished flag to ```true```, but the Form never gets true.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try to use static variable and static method to achieve that. If want to be thread-safe, you may consider to add lock in static method.